# Store the user and score in memory to print them all at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to print the username and score(generated in-game). Multiple users can log in and play the game, whenever users choose to see "score" it should display a score of all users along with name.
I want to store the multiple usernames and their score and print them when the "Score" option is selected.
I want the output to look like username, score.

```py
class user:
    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.scr = score
        self.name = name

    def addscr(self):
        self.scr += 1

    def getscr(self):
        return self.scr

    def getnm(self):
        return self.name
```

There are other classes for game.
below is an example output. this is what the score should look like when the user selects the "Score" option.
output
user1 = 2
user2 = 4

Comment: That isn't clear what you have for now and what you want

Comment: You mention two users in your example. How would we know you have two users to print out?

Comment: It is not clear as you show only the class declaration. What is your code ? please show a reproducible example we can copy paste and try. ANd also expected output. See [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is python, I would suggest not using any setters / getters as they are not needed. You can simply access any attribute by using the syntax "instance.attribute". Moreover, you can use a static user class specific attribute (that updates for any user) created. Which should contain all information about the users. For instance you can add a dictionary called users outside the init and store each user and their score inside it. Then, that attribute can be called from anywhere by referencing the class name.

```
class user:
    users = {}
    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.scr = score
        self.name = name
        user.users[name] = score
    # Also update values when score increases user.users[name] += 1
```

Here I gave an example using a dictionary with the names of the users as keys. Also, when updating the list / dictionary with users and their scores, make sure to call the class attribute (user.users[key]) instead of instance attribute. I hope this was helpful.